# unable to do vagrant halt

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, vagrant

When I try to run `vagrant halt` I get the following:

> An action 'halt' was attempted on the machine 'default', but another
>   process is already executing an action on the machine. Vagrant locks
>   each machine for access by only one process at a time. Please wait
>   until the other Vagrant process finishes modifying this machine, then
>   try again.
>
> If you believe this message is in error, please check the process
>   listing for any "ruby" or "vagrant" processes and kill them. Then try
>   again.

How can I found out what is using the machine 'default'?

Thanks!